# Count number in two columns and generate matrix?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I need to count the number based on two columns in a spreadsheet.

Suppose the file looks like this, ordered by name, department, hour:

[image: the original file]

And I need to count the hours of each person according to the department:

[image: the matrix]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and format it as code, please.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right answer but: In LibreOffice (also in Excel) you can use `Paste Special` tool and its option `Transpose`. Here you are [**a demo**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi436.gif).

Answer (score 2):

What you appear to want is called a *cross tabulation* or [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) .

While it's certainly possible to implement a solution using generic tools such as `awk`, `perl`, or `python`, the easiest approach IMHO would be to install [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) - you can then straightforwardly do

```
datamash --sort --whitespace --filler=0 crosstab 2,1 sum 3 < file
```

If there's only a single entry per pair (as appears to be the case in your example), then you can use `unique` in place of `sum`.

You can also do cross-tabulation in many spreadsheet applications - where it's often called *pivot tables*.

Comment: Thank you! i got your idea pivot and sussfully made it in excel!